# Apache proxy says hostname from SNI doesn't match hostname from HTTP

Tags: apache, ssl, https, proxy

I'm setting up a forward proxy on Apache 2.4, and I'm finding that every request for an HTTPS url results in a 400 response.

The apache error log shows:

> [ssl:error] AH02032: Hostname my.example.net provided via SNI and hostname stanford.edu provided via HTTP are different

What could I be doing wrong? My config is as follows:

```
Listen 3443

<VirtualHost *:3443>
  SSLEngine on
  ProxyRequests on
  ProxyVia off

  <Proxy *>
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.example.net/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.example.net/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.example.net/chain.pem

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/myerr.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried adding all of the following but to no effect:

- `SSLProxyEngine` with both `on` and `off`
- `SSLProxyVerify none`
- `AllowCONNECT 443`

I test the proxy by running:

```sh
https_proxy='https://my.example.net:3443/' curl 'https://stanford.edu/'
```

My server `my.example.net` is running Apache 2.4 on CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

The `curl` command appears to be the issue: instead of using an https scheme for the `https_proxy` variable, use `http` (so that there is only one TLS connection, and it goes right through to the destination host):

```sh
https_proxy='http://my.example.net:3443/' curl 'https://stanford.edu/'
```